# Marketo spam filter without Captcha

Tags: javascript, filter, spam

The help article below outlines Marketo spam filter that in included by default when using a form inside on a Marketo Landing Page (LP).  Is there an implementation of this spam filter for forms outside of Marketo LPs?

[Marketo Spam Filter](https://community.marketo.com/MarketoArticle?id=kA050000000KyqZ&src=comm) - please note this is located in the login protected community section of Marketo, so you will need to be logged in to view this link.

The forms on our site need be included in the pages so simply using an LP would not work for us.  Using iframed LP's of forms in our pages created an overhead to the load time of our pages as well as a duplication error in Google Analytics stating that we were referring ourselves to our site. Also as a condition we do not want to use Captcha due to the negative effects it has on quantity of form submissions.

Our main issue is not the submission of blank form fields.  We are getting numerous spam forms 10-15/week typically, but can ramp up to 10 in a night sporadically.  A typical spam form had a company name of “google” and comments that contain paragraphs of nonsense/links.

I have made multiple efforts to stop this issue which have proved useless.

I have tried to conditionally prevent submission if company name is equal to “google”, but for some reason this still submits.  I remove spaces and lowercase the value before testing against this constraint, but forms continue to submit.  I cannot replicate a scenario where this is possible on the front end so I am not sure how to fix this problem.

The second method I have attempted here is my implementation of a [honeypot method](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/10/honeypot-captcha.aspx) to have a hidden field that should remain blank, but spam bots fill it out.  Quite simply if this field contains anything, don't submit.

Here is the code I am currently running which is the "Submit" buttons onclick event function

```
  function formSubmit(elt) {
      var corp = document.getElementById('Corporate').value;
      var com = document.getElementById('Company').value.toLowerCase();
      if(com.indexOf("google") >= 0){
         return false;
      }
      else if(corp.length != 0){
        return false;
      }
      else{
        return Mkto.formSubmit(elt);
      }
  }
```

Has anyone run into this issue or know of a potential solution?  I have submitted a ticket to support, but figured I would post on here as well to see if the community knows of a solution to this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: That "honeypot" article is interesting, but does not fit my definition of a [honeypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29), which is something that actually collects data on the attacker (spammer) and uses it to build intelligence to mitigate other attacks.  Moreover, it's a hack, [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and only defeats basic attacks.  If scaled up, the spammers would merely adapt (though in the meanwhile, the JS/CSS requirements could help).